# запушить в новую ветку определенные файлы

Tags: git, git-push, git-branch

Есть репозиторий test с веткой master.
В нем файлы 1.txt 2.txt
Создаю новую ветку и перехожу в нее git checkout -b newBranch.
Далее создаю файл 3.txt

Вопрос. Как запушить в новую ветку только файл 3.txt
Если делаю git add 3.txt в конечном итоге в ветке newBranch имею все 3 файла, в то время как в master только начальные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запушится и так только 3.txt. Два других файла уже имеются в новой ветке с самого ее создания. Каждая новая ветка является точной копией той, из которой она создается.

Варианты решения:

1. Удалить файлы 1.txt и 2.txt в новой ветке.
2. Создавать новую ветку до коммита тех двух файлов в исходную.

*Но, честно говоря, непонятно, почему вам в новой ветке ненужны два исходные файла. Похоже, что вы хотите использовать гит не совсем для того, для чего он предназначен.*

Answer (score 0):

Прибей их в ветке, если мешают. Новая ветка создалась из мастера. а в мастере у тебя есть 2 файла. поэтому они и "переехали" в новую ветку